# Do while is not working correctly

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am making a grocery store java program which lists out options of items and adds them to the cart according to the users input. It works fine for the first option however after that the programs is not functioning correctly. I cannot seem to find the bug anywhere!

Ideally what I want it to ask is:

What would you like to add to your cart? enter the number

(have user enter the number)

how many?

(have user enter number)

Would you like to add anything else to your cart? (y/n)

(enter y or n)

Basically when the user inputs '1' it should add it to the cart etc, then ask if they want to add another item. It then prints "what would you like to add to your cart" When I input another item number it goes back to the beginning of the while loop and prints out "what would like to add to your cart" again instead of actually adding the item like it does with the first item.

**Picture of output of broken do while**

[image]

I've also provided the code:

```
do {        
    System.out.println("What would you like to add to your cart? Enter its corresponding number");
    choose = userin.nextInt();

    if(choose > 14) {
      System.out.println("please choose a valid option!"); 
      keepGoing = true;
    } else if(choose == 1) {
        System.out.println("how many?");    
        int quantity;
        quantity = userin.nextInt();
        cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.QUINOA, 7.00, quantity);      
    }
    System.out.print ("\nWould you like to add anything else to your cart (y/n)? ");
    keepShopping = userin.next();

    if(choose ==2) {
      System.out.println("What would you like to add to your cart? Enter its corresponding number");
      choose = userin.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("how many?");  
      int quantity;
      quantity = userin.nextInt();
      cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.ORGEGG, 3.45, quantity);
    }
    System.out.print ("\nWould you like to add anything else to your cart (y/n)? ");
    keepShopping = userin.next();
    System.out.println("What would you like to add to your cart? Enter its corresponding number");
    choose = userin.nextInt();

    if(choose == 3) {
      System.out.println("how many?");  
      int quantity;
      quantity = userin.nextInt();
      cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.CCNTW, 2.99, quantity);
      System.out.print ("\nWould you like to add anything else to your cart (y/n)? ");
      keepShopping = userin.next();

    }
}
while (keepShopping.equals("y"));

  if(keepShopping.equals("n")) {
     System.out.println("\n");
     Register.talking();
  }
  System.out.println(cart1);
  keepGoing = false;
}
```

Comment: "the programs is not functioning correctly" - What *does* happen? Does it end prematurely? Does it keep repeating the same question?

Comment: @Katana314 the picture demonstrates what happens. It prints out the incorrect following statement.

Comment: I can't see the picture: questions should stand on their own. And just the picture is not sufficient--you need to describe in words the difference between what's expected and what's happening.

Comment: Even looking at the picture, your do-while loop appears to be functioning correctly.

Comment: @DaveNewton basically when the user inputs '1' it should add it to the cart etc, then ask if they want to add another item. It then prints "what would you like to add to your cart" When I input another item number it goes back to the beginning of the while loop and prints out "what would like to add to your cart" again instead of actually adding the item like it does with the first item.

Comment: It's not going back to the beginning.  You prompt the user to enter if they want to add more things very early in the loop, and then ask them what they want to add to the cart after that, and before you hit the end of the loop.

Comment: @azurefrog it is not working correctly it should not be asking "What would you like to add to your cart? enter the corresponding number" after I enter a number. It should instead ask "how many?"

Comment: holy code duplication batman! don’t repeat the same code over and over

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the info. Please put that info into the actual question so it stands on its own :)

Comment: @PatrickParker True, but probably best to focus on getting something working first.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added it thanks for that I should have been slightly clearer!

Comment: Why not paste the output?

Comment: @Antoniossss why so much focus on the output instead of trying to help out?

Comment: @Chris simple - no output in question to refer to. No chances to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your code is you are not using **else if. So the loop will not reach the while condition until it execute all the if case.**

Here is the working code. I also refactored your code to make it easy.

```
public class Cart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String keepShopping;
        int quantity;
        do {
            System.out.println("What would you like to add to your cart? Enter its corresponding number");
            int choose = userin.nextInt();

            if (choose > 14) {
                System.out.println("please choose a valid option!");
            }
            System.out.println("how many?");
            quantity = userin.nextInt();

            if (choose == 1) {
                cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.QUINOA, 7.00, quantity);
            }
            else if (choose == 2) {
                cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.ORGEGG, 3.00, quantity);
            }
            else if (choose == 3) {
                cart1.addToCart(FoodItems.CCNTW, 1.00, quantity);
            }
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to add anything else to your cart (y/n)? ");
            keepShopping = userin.next();
        } while (keepShopping.equals("y"));
        if (keepShopping.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! I see that adding the would you like to add anything else being put outside of the last else if resolved it being repeating.